# Rails couldn't find file 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What can be a problem? I have include this inside my Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

This inside my application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require jquery
*= require jquery-ui-all
```

And this inside my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I am constantly receiving this error:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery'
```

Comment: Do you have CSS files named "jquery" and "jquery-ui-all"? Also, what else is in the error or around the error?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see it anywhere. Where should it be located?

Comment: @nikkon226, it says there is jquery file missing in application.css:12.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to delete the two lines calling jquery in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Comment: @nikkon226, thanks. It works! Put your answer as a separate post and I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the two lines referencing "jquery" in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` in order to clear up your error message about it not being able to find stylesheets with those names.